# Inconsistent results in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Running the following code repeatedly generates inconsistent results.  So far, I have only seen two outputs.  The results get repeated any random number of times before switching to the other results, which then also repeat any random number of times before switching back again.

Why is this happening?

In this example I could use the indexing window function and include an `orderBy()` before I use `%` to modify the single column, but my real example, I do not have this option, so this is not a solution for me.

```
import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

window = W.rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.currentRow)
testCol = [tuple([x]) for x in range(1,5000)]

# repeatedly re-run from here:
testDF = (spark.createDataFrame(testCol,['testCol'])
              .withColumn('testCol',
                          F.when(F.col('testCol') % 2 == 0, 
                             F.col('testCol'))
                          .otherwise(0.0))              
              .withColumn('int', F.lit(1))
              .withColumn('index', F.sum('int').over(window))
              .drop('int') 
)

testDF.show()
```

Result 1 (expected):

```
+-------+-----+
|testCol|index|
+-------+-----+
|    0.0|    1|
|    2.0|    2|
|    0.0|    3|
|    4.0|    4|
|    0.0|    5|
|    6.0|    6|
|    0.0|    7|
|    8.0|    8|
|    0.0|    9|
|   10.0|   10|
|    0.0|   11|
|   12.0|   12|
|    0.0|   13|
|   14.0|   14|
|    0.0|   15|
|   16.0|   16|
|    0.0|   17|
|   18.0|   18|
|    0.0|   19|
|   20.0|   20|
+-------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Result 2 (not expected):

```
+-------+-----+
|testCol|index|
+-------+-----+
|    0.0|    1|
| 2050.0|    2|
|    0.0|    3|
| 2052.0|    4|
|    0.0|    5|
| 2054.0|    6|
|    0.0|    7|
| 2056.0|    8|
|    0.0|    9|
| 2058.0|   10|
|    0.0|   11|
| 2060.0|   12|
|    0.0|   13|
| 2062.0|   14|
|    0.0|   15|
| 2064.0|   16|
|    0.0|   17|
| 2066.0|   18|
|    0.0|   19|
| 2068.0|   20|
+-------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

This code also produces the exact same inconsistent output:

```
testDF = (spark.createDataFrame(testCol,['testCol'])
              .repartition(1) # to address how monotonically_increasing_id works
              .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())            
              .withColumn('testCol',
                          F.when(F.col('testCol') % 2 == 0, 
                             F.col('testCol'))
                          .otherwise(0.0))              
)

testDF.show()
```

Comment: without ordering why do you expect the output to be same in all the runs? for sure that output will be random.

Comment: But it is not random, only the two outputs.  The output is also exactly the same if I use code with the `monotonically_increasing_id()` function.  Why is that?

Comment: Thats just coincidence as `monotonically_increasing_id()` will generate random numbers in increasing order.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) says it puts the ***"partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits."***  These are not random numbers.  Using with `.repartition(1)` this returns only the record number as evidenced by the 'index' column always starting at the interger '0', and checking the max value of the integer column returns '4999', the total number of DataFrame rows.

Comment: did you read **The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive.** in [inbuilt functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonically_increasing_id--) doc?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan That is the beginning part of the exact same documentation that I linked to and quoted, you have to read both together.  The part I quoted above tells you ***exactly*** how the numbers are generated.  The ***"partition ID"*** and ***"record number"*** are ***not*** random numbers.

Comment: aren't you seeing **but not consecutive** words ? it means **random numbers but in increasing order** and thats what I said in my previous comment

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  yes, and that is true when you also consider that the ***"The current implementation puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits."***  And as I said before,  The ***"partition ID"*** and ***"record number"*** are ***NOT***  random numbers.

Comment: How do you know that repartition will generate the same partition id for consecutive processings? From what I know is repartion will shuffle all data to be collected as one partition. And that partition is one executor. So how do you know that the same executor will be assigned as soon as you do repartition. And one more point, how do you know the record numbers for each row will be same for each processing when you haven't ordered the rows???

Comment: @RameshMaharjan For whatever reason, if I use `repartition(1)` I always get monotonically increasing, unique, ***and*** consecutive integers.  This would make sense if Spark sets the first partition ID to '0' which would not change the output 64-bit integer.  If the order of records (rows) changes ***randomly*** each time it gets executed, why only the two possible outputs that also just happen to exactly match the two outputs of the window function?  It is always the same two outputs, no matter how many times I restart the SparkSession, or even run on a different cluster.

Comment: ok then. Good luck with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: **Spark makes no guarantees about local or global ordering unless you force it to do so** so the output of this calculation is strictly undefined. The fact that the output shows some semi-consistent patterns is not a guarantee, it's just a side effect of how Spark happens to perform these operations in practice.

I can reproduce the behavior you see, and the randomness is coming from the window aggregation. For whatever reason the `spark.createDataFrame` operation is stable:

1. the resulting DataFrame has two partitions
2. the first 2048 records get assigned to partition 0 and the remaining 2951 get assigned to partition 1
3. inside each partition, the records are ordered by the initial value of `testCol`

(I'll emphasize that none of this is *guaranteed* to be stable, it just looks like it happens to be stable in practice.)

However, when you apply the window function, no ordering is specified but Spark has to put them in *some* global order to calculate a windowed sum.

In this case, the operation appears to not be stable: Spark just unions the two partitions together in an arbitrary sequence. Sometimes the records from partition 0 come first, sometimes partition 1 comes first. Then the window operation runs over whatever order the rows already happen to be in.

The same happens with the `repartition(1)` in your second DataFrame: Spark randomly unions the two partitions into a single one, and the fact that any internal ordering of the rows at all is maintained is just laziness (it's cheaper not to shuffle the data than to shuffle it).

This is somewhat more clear if you explicitly add the initial partition IDs after creating the DataFrame:

```
testDF = (spark.createDataFrame(testCol,['testCol'])
              .withColumn("partition_id", F.spark_partition_id())
              .repartition(1) # to address how monotonically_increasing_id works
              .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())            
              .withColumn('testCol',
                          F.when(F.col('testCol') % 2 == 0, 
                             F.col('testCol'))
                          .otherwise(0.0))              
)
testDF.show(6)
```

Sample output (although as in your experience it switches back and forth):

```
+-------+------------+---+
|testCol|partition_id| id|
+-------+------------+---+
|    0.0|           1|  0|
| 2050.0|           1|  1|
|    0.0|           1|  2|
| 2052.0|           1|  3|
|    0.0|           1|  4|
| 2054.0|           1|  5|
+-------+------------+---+
only showing top 6 rows
```

The overarching point is that you can't rely on ordering in Spark (global or local) unless you specify it explicitly with an `.orderBy()` method on the DataFrame itself or in the window definition.